# How to skip Deleting route entry from Routing table during NetLink Socket Ip Deletion

Tags: linux, command-line, iptables, netlink

I am using NetLink Socket To delete an IP from the interface. While Deleting the IP, It's deleting the Route Entry also from the Route table.

But I want to keep that route entry in the routing table though I am deleting the IP from the Interface.